# js - incorporate an object into an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, array-merge

I have an array structured as follows:

```
const screens = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    options: {
      headerTitle: 'Book Title',
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'Bill',
    options: {
      headerTitle: 'Another title',
    },
  },
];
```

and a piece of data that I need to insert into the 'options:' above. The data I can reshape at will. It could be:

```
const header = {
    headerStyle: {
      borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
      borderColor: 'black',
    },
};
```

or

```
header2 = [
  {
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
  },
];
```

The end goal is to have:

```
const screens = [
      {
        name: 'John',
        options: {
          headerTitle: 'Book Title',
          headerStyle: {
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 0.5,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Bill',
        options: {
          headerTitle: 'Another title',
          headerStyle: {
            bordercolor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 0.5,
        },
      },
    ];
```

I have been googling the spread operator but I don't seem to be able to get the two merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to [*map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the existing array to a new one with your options merged

```js
const screens = [{"name":"John","options":{"headerTitle":"Book Title"}},{"name":"Bill","options":{"headerTitle":"Another title"}}]

const header = {
  headerStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: 'black'
  }
}

const merged = screens.map(screen => ({
  ...screen,
  options: {
    ...screen.options,
    ...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(header))
  }
}))

console.log(merged)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

One thing to note here is that without the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(header))`, each object in your array will share the same `headerStyle` object reference. There may be simpler ways to break the object references using spread syntax but given the potential dynamic nature of your object to be merged, using the `JSON` methods is a convenient catch-all.

Comment: Thanks. No, sharing the same obj reference is not an issue here.

Comment: also can prevent object reference by extract using three dots `...`

Comment: @nay then you'd need to know the structure of the object and OP says _"The data I can reshape at will"_. It also gets fiddly when there are multiple properties

Answer (score 1):

if this could help you.
just loop the array and append headerStyle.the three dots means extract data,intend to prevent reference.

```js
const screens = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    options: {
      headerTitle: 'Book Title',
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'Bill',
    options: {
      headerTitle: 'Another title',
    },
  },
];

const header = {
    headerStyle: {
      borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
      borderColor: 'black',
    },
};

screens.forEach(item=>{item.options['headerStyle']={...header.headerStyle}})

console.log(screens)
```